# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.vcs.git

Tags: python, postgresql, visual-studio-code, pip

При установке `psycopg2` происходит ошибка

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip._internal.vcs.git
```

[image: ошибка]

Comment: Попробуйте для начала обновить `pip`: `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Answer (score 0):

Помогла установка pip через: curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python